# Is it possible to log client-side sub-resource integrity errors with javascript?

Tags: javascript, subresource-integrity

I am looking for a way to intercept the [sub-resource integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) error messages that are generated when any integrity hash values are invalid. Is there any way to intercept these events using on-page JavaScript, or detect if a node has an invalid `integrity` property?

For example these error messages:

`None of the “sha384” hashes in the integrity attribute match the content of the sub-resource.`

`Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://path/to/file' with computed SHA-256 integrity '[hash]'. The resource has been blocked.`